# Check column by column in R

Tags: r, character

I have a problem with matching two rows in a table

```
r1 <- "ghuytut3jilujshdftgu"
r2 <- "ghuytuthjilujshdftgu"
df2 <- as.data.frame(rbind(unlist(strsplit(r1, "")), unlist(strsplit(r2, ""))))
```

I want to specify a column number (say column number 5) and find how many columns to the right and left of the column the the two sequences are identical. I want a mechanism for comparing these two strings character by character (column by column) starting from the centre and scanning outwards, returning the number of matching characters until the first difference is encountered

Comment: so... `ident<-TRUE; while(ident) { ident<-df2[1,5-j]==df2[2,5+j];j<j+1}`  ?  Then `j` will tell you (or `j-1` ) how far you got before a mismatch.  Or maybe it's easier to split the rows, reverse the order of the LH parts, and do some string function magic.

Comment: could you potnetially explain the last bit of the answer in a bit more detail/

Comment: Well, like `r1right<-df2[1,1:5] ; r1left <- df1[1,6:(dim(df2)[2])]` . Then `r1left<-rev(r1left)` , and then find or write some function which counts how many characters are the same (`r1left[j]==r1right[j]`)  . Probably not worth the effort :-)

Comment: Why are you reposting basically [the same question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20970770/matching-of-patterns-in-r), furthermore, a question you commented has been answered?

Answer (score 1):

I think the function I've seen that's most helpful for "number in a row" questions is `rle`, which computes the run length encoding of a vector. For instance, you can see the run lengths of characters being the same or different in your strings with:

```
r1 = "ghuytut3jilujshdftgu"
r2 = "ghuytuthjilujshdftgu"
spl1 = unlist(strsplit(r1, ""))
spl2 = unlist(strsplit(r2, ""))
rle(spl1 == spl2)
# Run Length Encoding
#   lengths: int [1:3] 7 1 12
#   values : logi [1:3] TRUE FALSE TRUE
```

For your problem, you want to compute the run length of matches starting from some interior index `i`, both forward and backward. Here's an implementation of that, using `rle` (function assumes strings are same length and `i` is a valid index; forward and backward run lengths include the character at index `i`):

```
fxn = function(r1, r2, i) {
  spl1 = unlist(strsplit(r1, ""))
  spl2 = unlist(strsplit(r2, ""))
  if (spl1[i] != spl2[i]) {
    return(list(forward=0, backward=0))
  }
  rle.backward = rle(spl1[i:1] == spl2[i:1])
  rle.forward = rle(spl1[i:nchar(r1)] == spl2[i:nchar(r2)])
  return(list(forward=rle.forward$lengths[1], backward=rle.backward$lengths[1]))
}
fxn(r1, r2, 5)
# $forward
# [1] 3
# 
# $backward
# [1] 5

fxn(r1, r2, 9)
# $forward
# [1] 12
# 
# $backward
# [1] 1
```

Comment: +1 for using my favorite function.  Not sure how well this scales (time penalty) for very large strings.

Comment: @CarlWitthoft good point -- it would probably be slower than a loop in the case of long strings with many differences.